# How to do conversion of units between two tables in SAP HANA Database

Tags: sql, database, select, hana

Hi I stumble upon some problem with **SAP HANA database please note**. I have some toy example problem. I tried to come up with solution, but I cannot figure out.
I have two tables one of **Volume table**

```
Row MATERIAL    BASE_UOM    PERIOD  SUMMAND
1   55555        KG         201106     99
2   55555        KG         201204     16
3   55555        KG         201301     71
4   55555        KG         201411     83
5   55555        KG         201509     21
6   55555        PAL        201510     64
7   55555        PAL        201511     69
8   55555        KG         201512     55
9   55555        ZRS        201601     81
10  55555        KG         201602     3
11  55555        KG         201603     74
12  55555        KG         201604     58
13  55555        ZRS        201605     8
14  55555        KG         201606     22
```

The second table is **Conversion Table**

```
Row MATERIAL    UNIT    BASE_UOM    UOMN1D     UOMZ1D    Conversion Rate
1   55555        KG        KG        1          1            1
2   55555        CSE       KG        1,000.00   2,016.00    2.016
3   55555        ST        KG        1,000.00   56          0.056
4   55555        LAY       KG        100        3,024.00    30.24
5   55555        PAL       KG        100        54,432.00   544.32
6   55555        ZDK       KG        59,778.00  54,432.00   0.910569106
7   55555        ZSE       KG        59,778.00  54,432.00   0.910569106
8   55555        ZNO       KG        59,778.00  54,432.00   0.910569106
9   55555        ZFI       KG        59,778.00  54,432.00   0.910569106
10  55555        ZRV       KG        1,000.00   57          0.057
11  55555        ZRS       KG        1,000.00   2,052.00    2.052
```

*Please bear in mind that Row column is indicative!*

**Key between tables is MATERIAL column.**

I would like to convert all fields in column **SUMMAND (Volume table)**, when there are not KG in **BASE_UOM** column **Volume table** e.g. in row 6 is PAL into KG or row 13 ZRS into KG. If we are in situation that we have KG we do not need to update column **SUMMAND**. To convert PAL into KG I need to look up at **Conversion Table** at  **MATERIAL** and **UNIT** Column (look up PAL field) and get row 5 from **Conversion Rate** column (**UOMZ1D/UOMN1D**) 544.32*64 (64 is coming from **Volume table** row 6 Column **SUMMAND**) and so on.  Finally, each individual **MATERIAL** has its own conversion rate.

The final output of **Volume table** should look like this. Row 6,7,9,13 is updated correctly.

```
Row MATERIAL    BASE_UOM    PERIOD  SUMMAND
1   55555        KG         201106    99
2   55555        KG         201204    16
3   55555        KG         201301    71
4   55555        KG         201411    83
5   55555        KG         201509    21
6   55555        PAL        201510    34836.48
7   55555        PAL        201511    37558.08
8   55555        KG         201512    55
9   55555        ZRS        201601    166.212
10  55555        KG         201602    3
11  55555        KG         201603    74
12  55555        KG         201604    58
13  55555        ZRS        201605    16.416
14  55555        KG         201606    22
```

How I can check for every possible combination to convert all units into KG between this two tables. Would like to suggest me how to scale it, if I have longer list conversion between UNIT and BASE_UOM from **Conversion Table** imagine like 90 unique possible combinations. What SQL query I need to build in order to achieve the desired output. Any kind of solution are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you might want to use an **inner join** to match up the conversion factors to the material.

Something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
     v.MATERIAL
   , v.BASE_UOM as ORIGINAL_UOM
   , v.PERIOD
   , c.UNIT  as TARGET_OUM
   , (c.UOMZ1D/c.UOMN1D) * v.SUMMAND as SUMMAND_TARGET_OUM

FROM 
            VOLUMES v
INNER JOIN CONVERSION c
ON (v.MATERIAL, v.BASE_UOM) 
 = (c.MATERIAL, c.UNIT)
```

This query relies on that there is one and only one matching entry in the conversion table for each possible `material/base_uom` combination.
If no match can be found, the corresponding record from `VOLUMES` will be omitted in the output.

It's obviously possible to design this more resilient to missing data (e.g. by fall-back output of unchanged data or transitive lookups), but the given solution is straight forward and easy to understand and debug.

Note, that this does **not** make use of SAP HANA's built-in unit-of-measure conversion functions. As these are designed to replicate the UOM conversion logic of SAP NetWeaver -based applications, these are probably not what you want in this case.

Comment: Hats off to you, what a brilliant solution. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. Super kudos for you.

Comment: One question I cannot understand what you mean by this "e.g. by fall-back output of unchanged data or transitive lookups" would you like to elaborate more please? I am no familiar with these concepts.

Comment: Ok, by "fall-back" I mean to have a defined behaviour when **no** matching conversion rule can be found. That could be an error message or do return the original data, etc. 
By "transitive lookups" I mean, that if you want to convert UOM X to Z but don't have this conversion in the rules table. You could look up X -> Y and Y -> Z to get to the desired result. 
As mentioned, implementing those would be more complicated.